# Vagrant + Puppet + Nginx: cannot open ports

Tags: nginx, vagrant, puppet

I'm getting nuts.

I have a Vagrant VM that has port 80 and port 22 open. I'm trying to open the port 443 to add HTTPS capacities.

I have added in my `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.define "staging.mojjo.fr", primary: true do |web|
  web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
  web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 443
  [... other config]
end
```

but anyways this wasn't there before so I guessed this doesn't have any effect. This might be related to the fact that in vagrant it is not possible to open <1000 ports.

So I moved to `manifests/profiles/firewall.pp` where I found:

```
   firewall { '099 allow ssh' :
     port   => [22],
     proto  => tcp,
     action => accept,
   }
```

but no reference to port 80. Then I found `manifests/profiles/nginx.pp`:

```
 firewall { '100 allow http' :
   port   => [80],
   proto  => tcp,
   action => accept,
 }
```

So I changed it to:

```
firewall { '100 allow http and https nginx level' :
  dport   => [80, 443],
  proto  => tcp,
  action => accept,
}
```

and added (in case) in `manifests/profiles/firewall.pp`:

```
firewall { '100 allow http and https firewall level' :
  dport   => [80, 443],
  proto  => tcp,
  action => accept,
}
```

But it still won't work.

I ran `vagrant provision example.com` along with `vagrant reload example.com` in case.

I get some message saying:

```
==> example.com: Rsyncing folder: /home/augustin/Workspace/example/manifests/ => /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-a11d1078b1b1f2e3bdea27312f6ba513
==> example.com: Rsyncing folder: /home/augustin/Workspace/example/modules/ => /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-185d399cf69f210a03067116106838bf
```

Which make me feel like some cached data is used sometimes, which doesn't help debugging. Any idea of to prevent this from happening?

My HTTPS works because I tried to set it on port 80 and my `https://example.com:80/test.html` did work.

So it's only port 443 I can't figure how to open. 
Any idea where this should be? How can I test each step to find where it doesn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully You have solved Your issue already, but CentOS have the behavior to close https in firewall. 
Try this. 
Have You tried to open up a port with this command.

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=https 
firewall-cmd --add-service=https --permanent 
firewall-cmd --reload
```

After that try `nmap -sT -O example.com` .